# Error viewing Excel sheets on mobile

Tags: excel-services, mobile

I'm using SharePoint 2013, whenever I try to view an Excel file embedded in a SharePoint page through my mobile it gives me this message

> We can't start Excel mobile viewer because it may be turned off. Please contact your help desk.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this question credits to this [article](http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=cant-start-excel-mobile-viewer) so basically it's a sharepoint feature that you need to enable through command line. `Enable-SPFeature -Identity E995E28B-9BA8-4668-9933-CF5C146D7A9F -Url "insert site url" -force​`